# Python throws ascii codec can't encode when parsing xml

Tags: python, xml, unicode

I was running the following code in Python:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('dplp_11.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
f = open('workfile', 'w')
for country in root.findall('article'):
    rank = country.find('year').text
    name = country.find('title').text

    if(int(rank)>2009):
        f.write(name)
        auth = country.findall('author')
        for a in auth:
            #print str(a)
            f.write(a.text)
            f.write(',')
        f.write('\n')
```

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 14, in <module>
    f.write(a.text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I was trying to parse the dblp data which looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dblp>
<article mdate="2011-01-11" key="journals/acta/Saxena96">
<author>Sanjeev Saxena</author>
<title>Parallel Integer Sorting and Simulation Amongst CRCW Models.</title>
<pages>607-619</pages>
<year>1996</year>
<volume>33</volume>
<journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
<number>7</number>
<url>db/journals/acta/acta33.html#Saxena96</url>
<ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF03036466</ee>
</article>
<article mdate="2015-07-14" key="journals/acta/BozapalidisFR12">
<author>Symeon Bozapalidis</author>
<author>Zoltán Fülöp 0001</author>
<author>George Rahonis</author>
<title>Equational weighted tree transformations.</title>
<pages>29-52</pages>
<year>2012</year>
<volume>49</volume>
<journal>Acta Inf.</journal>
<number>1</number>
<ee>http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00236-011-0148-5</ee>
<url>db/journals/acta/acta49.html#BozapalidisFR12</url>
</article>
</dblp>
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Note that it is the `f.write()` line that throws the exception. It is not the *XML parsing* that is the issue here, it is writing to the text file that causes the problem. `f.write(u'Zolt\xe1n')`  would give you the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.text` is a Unicode object, but you are trying to write it to a plain Python 2 file object:

```
f.write(a.text)
```

The `f.write()` method only takes a *byte* string (type `str`), triggering an implicit encode to the ASCII codec, triggering your exception if the text can't be encoded as ASCII.

You'll either need to explicitly encode it with a codec that can encode your data, or use a `io.open()` file object that does the encoding for you.

Encoding explicitly to UTF-8 would work, for example:

```
f.write(a.text.encode('utf8'))
```

or use `io.open()` with an explicit encoding:

```
import io

# ...

f = io.open('workfile', 'w', encoding='utf8')
```

after which all calls to `f.write()` *must* be Unicode objects; prefix any literal strings with `u`:

```
for a in auth:
    f.write(a.text)
    f.write(u',')
f.write(u'\n')
```

Comment: When i did this i got another error saying "for country in findall(article) Syntax error:invalid syntax"

Comment: @SAMAHA: you didn't close the `)` parentheses in a preceding line then.

Comment: :That error is solved.But got another error saying "f.write(name) write() argument 1 must be unicode ,not str"

Comment: My python version is 2.7

Comment: @SAMAHA: right, all other writes must be unicode then too; use `u','` and `u'\n'`. I'll update.

Comment: I got it solved but another error saying "'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)" appeared

Comment: Glad the first problem was solved! You have an entirely new problem now, where you are triggering another implicit encoding. Perhaps you are concatenating a plain `str` object with a `unicode` object. Post a new question that demonstrates the issue with a [mcve] (like I did for this question.

Comment: Not only that error,errors for u'\xb1',u'\xed',etc.. are coming.So i need to resolve problem for all the special characters.

Comment: @SAMAHA: Those characters all have in common that they are *not part of the ASCII standard* and can't be encoded to ASCII. Perhaps you want to read up about [Python and Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) before you continue to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Actually the xml which i am using has iso encoding.So what should i do?

Comment: @SAMAHA: I already told you what to do. Post a new question that demonstrates your problem clearly. Include valid input data, the full error message, and what you expected to happen instead.

Comment: @SAMAHA: I can't do anything else *here* because there are any number of things you could be doing wrong. *This* question, writing the authors to a file, was resolved; with my changes that part works.